# IWebDriver opens a blank data window after clicking on button instead of the loaded content that suppose to be - selenium c#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have selenium.support version 3.141.0, chrome driver version 2.43.0 and Google Chrome version 71.0.3578.98 and Selenium.ChromeDriver.dll 2.43.0.

when i click on a certain button a new window should be open. i click on the button and if i use any action on the browser for example `new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)).Until(IsPageLoaded);`  the window stop to load and stay blank data. why can't i get the browser to load it's content?

Edit: when the new window opens i change the the driver to the latest windowHandel and use the webDriverWait from above to wait which result in a blank data window, but if i use thread.sleep after changing the windowHandel the window load its content

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB Is that clearer?

Comment: When you are clicking on a certain button the _page is already loaded_. Perhaps you should be looking at additional _windowHandle_ or an _alert_.

Comment: @DebanjanB when the new window opens i change the the driver to the latest windowHandel and use the webDriverWait from above to wait which result in a blank data window, but if i use thread.sleep after changing the windowHandel the window load its content

Comment: Can you update all these information within the main question?

Comment: @DebanjanB i will

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a explicit wait for a element to be visible on the new window. That would ensure it waits for the contents to load up

Comment: hi thanks, i tried to wait for an element and still gets the same blank window. do you know what can cause this behavior?